# Java streams to find all apart from Max

Tags: java, stream, max

I am still learning java streams and could not figure out a solution for my problem.

scenario:

I have a list of objects which each object has an identifier called stageNo.

So basically what I am trying to do is filter out the max objects according to stageNo and set a method a specific value.

**code:**

```
Object currentObject = new Object();
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

objects
       .stream()
       .filter(object -> object.stageNoCalculate == currentObject.getStageNo)
       .filter(object -> object.executionDate != null)
       .max(Comparator.comparing(Object::getStageNo)
       .map(object -> {
            object.setFlag(1);
            return object;
         }).get();
```

this will result with the object that has the max stageNo and will set the flag method accordingly to 1.
this works properly with no issues.

now I am trying to find all object that meets filtering but instead of max,
find everything **apart** from max and setFlag(0) instead.

I am not entirely sure on the way to do so, tried looking for solutions, however could not find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort your stream from max to min, and skip the first element.

```java
objects
  .stream()
  .filter(object -> object.stageNoCalculate == currentObject.getStageNo)
  .filter(object -> object.executionDate != null)
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::getStageNo).reversed())
  .skip(1) //Skip the first element, which is the max
  .forEach(object -> {
            object.setFlag(0);
            return object;
         });
```

Comment: It won't since the max value is an identifier (a unique value) 'stageNo' and it runs from 1-10